# Understanding indexing issues in Pandas 0.8.1 (and 0.11)

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

Here is an example from an IPython session where some straightforward indexing and assignments to a Pandas DataFrame work and some don't work when they seem straightforward:

```
In [652]: dfrm = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

In [653]: dfrm
Out[653]:
          A         B         C
0  0.777147  0.558404  0.424222
1  0.906354  0.111197  0.492625
2  0.011354  0.468661  0.056303
3  0.118818  0.117526  0.649210
4  0.746045  0.583369  0.962173
5  0.374871  0.285712  0.868599
6  0.223596  0.963223  0.012154
7  0.969879  0.043160  0.891143
8  0.527701  0.992965  0.073797
9  0.553854  0.969303  0.523098

In [654]: dfrm['A'][dfrm.A > 0.5] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

In [655]: dfrm
Out[655]:
          A         B         C
0  1.000000  0.558404  0.424222
1  2.000000  0.111197  0.492625
2  0.011354  0.468661  0.056303
3  0.118818  0.117526  0.649210
4  3.000000  0.583369  0.962173
5  0.374871  0.285712  0.868599
6  0.223596  0.963223  0.012154
7  4.000000  0.043160  0.891143
8  5.000000  0.992965  0.073797
9  6.000000  0.969303  0.523098

In [656]: dfrm[['B','C']][dfrm.A > 0.5] = 100*np.random.rand(6,2)

In [657]: dfrm
Out[657]:
          A         B         C
0  1.000000  0.558404  0.424222
1  2.000000  0.111197  0.492625
2  0.011354  0.468661  0.056303
3  0.118818  0.117526  0.649210
4  3.000000  0.583369  0.962173
5  0.374871  0.285712  0.868599
6  0.223596  0.963223  0.012154
7  4.000000  0.043160  0.891143
8  5.000000  0.992965  0.073797
9  6.000000  0.969303  0.523098

In [658]: dfrm[dfrm.A > 0.5] = 100*np.random.rand(6,3)

In [659]: dfrm
Out[659]:
           A          B          C
0  27.738118  18.812116  46.369840
1  35.335223  58.365611   7.773464
2   0.011354   0.468661   0.056303
3   0.118818   0.117526   0.649210
4  97.439481  98.621074  69.816171
5   0.374871   0.285712   0.868599
6   0.223596   0.963223   0.012154
7  53.609637  30.952762  81.379502
8  68.473117  16.261694  91.092718
9  82.253724  94.979991  72.571951

In [660]: dfrm[dfrm.A > 0.5] = 0.5*dfrm[dfrm.A > 0.5]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-660-35fb8e212806> in <module>()
----> 1 dfrm[dfrm.A > 0.5] = 0.5*dfrm[dfrm.A > 0.5]

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   1707             self._boolean_set(key, value)
   1708         elif isinstance(key, (np.ndarray, list)):
-> 1709             return self._set_item_multiple(key, value)
   1710         else:
   1711             # set column

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _set_item_multiple(self, keys, value)
   1728     def _set_item_multiple(self, keys, value):
   1729         if isinstance(value, DataFrame):
-> 1730             assert(len(value.columns) == len(keys))
   1731             for k1, k2 in zip(keys, value.columns):
   1732                 self[k1] = value[k2]

AssertionError:
```

Can anyone explain why some (but not all) of these work, and why the final one actually induces as error?

Update:

We have Pandas 0.11 installed, but it's not the default version for development so it's only a sandbox sort of thing for me right now. But even when I repeat this example in 0.11, I see the same assignment problems, except that the last example now works correctly with no error. But the muddled-ness of the conventions for how to invoke the original DataFrame's `__setitem__` are still there:

```
Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 11 2012, 17:52:16)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
Type "credits", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
Hello
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.__version__
'0.11.0'
>>> dfrm = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dfrm = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> dfrm
          A         B         C
0  0.745516  0.062613  0.147684
1  0.369141  0.447022  0.114963
2  0.820178  0.946806  0.687971
3  0.771971  0.934799  0.633633
4  0.828249  0.065587  0.848788
5  0.433796  0.740885  0.160140
6  0.663891  0.753134  0.849269
7  0.647054  0.962267  0.453865
8  0.345706  0.030634  0.058697
9  0.994135  0.990536  0.436903
>>> dfrm[dfrm.A > 0.5]
          A         B         C
0  0.745516  0.062613  0.147684
2  0.820178  0.946806  0.687971
3  0.771971  0.934799  0.633633
4  0.828249  0.065587  0.848788
6  0.663891  0.753134  0.849269
7  0.647054  0.962267  0.453865
9  0.994135  0.990536  0.436903
>>> len(dfrm[dfrm.A > 0.5])
7
>>> dfrm['A'][dfrm.A > 0.5] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> dfrm
          A         B         C
0  1.000000  0.062613  0.147684
1  0.369141  0.447022  0.114963
2  2.000000  0.946806  0.687971
3  3.000000  0.934799  0.633633
4  4.000000  0.065587  0.848788
5  0.433796  0.740885  0.160140
6  5.000000  0.753134  0.849269
7  6.000000  0.962267  0.453865
8  0.345706  0.030634  0.058697
9  7.000000  0.990536  0.436903
>>> dfrm[['B','C']][dfrm.A > 0.5] = 100*np.random.rand(7,2)
>>> dfrm
          A         B         C
0  1.000000  0.062613  0.147684
1  0.369141  0.447022  0.114963
2  2.000000  0.946806  0.687971
3  3.000000  0.934799  0.633633
4  4.000000  0.065587  0.848788
5  0.433796  0.740885  0.160140
6  5.000000  0.753134  0.849269
7  6.000000  0.962267  0.453865
8  0.345706  0.030634  0.058697
9  7.000000  0.990536  0.436903
>>> dfrm[dfrm.A > 0.5] = 0.5*dfrm[dfrm.A > 0.5]
>>> dfrm
          A         B         C
0  0.500000  0.031306  0.073842
1  0.369141  0.447022  0.114963
2  1.000000  0.473403  0.343985
3  1.500000  0.467400  0.316816
4  2.000000  0.032794  0.424394
5  0.433796  0.740885  0.160140
6  2.500000  0.376567  0.424635
7  3.000000  0.481133  0.226933
8  0.345706  0.030634  0.058697
9  3.500000  0.495268  0.218452
>>>
```

Second Update:

Here's another super unexpected behavior:

```
In [681]: id(dfrm.A)
Out[681]: 298480536

In [682]: id(dfrm.A)
Out[682]: 298480536

In [683]: id(dfrm.A)
Out[683]: 298480536

In [684]: id(dfrm['A'])
Out[684]: 298480536

In [685]: id(dfrm['A'])
Out[685]: 298480536

In [686]: id(dfrm['A'])
Out[686]: 298480536

In [687]: id(dfrm[['A']])
Out[687]: 281536912

In [688]: id(dfrm[['A']])
Out[688]: 281535824

In [689]: id(dfrm[['A']])
Out[689]: 281536336
```

Comment: could really be worth updating to 0.11 (soon 0.12), much improved indexing. I don't get any errors following this code.

Comment: The error is one thing. But the really counterintuitive convention about `dfrm[['B', 'C']]` returning a new object and then calling `__setitem__` whereas `dfrm['A']` calls `__setitem__` on the original object is very hard to understand. Especially since `dfrm[dfrm.A > 0.5]` also returns a new object, but somehow supports `__setitem__` on the original object.

Comment: yeah, using multiple []s is pretty hairy, and will give inconsistent, definitely recommend the upgrade for better indexing assignment.

Comment: FYI, I think you can use ``.ix`` in 0.8.1 (similar to the way Andy uses ``.loc`` below), not 100% sure though

Comment: I have had far worse results and inconsistencies with `.ix`. I can post more, but I think reconciling the conventions between views, copies, and `__setitem__` for `.ix` is a lost cause (again, in both versions).

Comment: All operations return a new objects, except if ``inplace=True`` (with some methods), OR, specific ``__setitem__`` assignments via ``.loc/.ix/.iloc``. ``[]`` assignement works too (but only works when not-chained, e.g. ``df['series'][df['series']>5] = 5`` is REALLY tricky and you just shouldn't do it)

Comment: This is false. For example, print out `id(dfrm.A)` several times and then print out `id(dfrm[['A','B']])` multiple times. Some things return references to the same object, some don't, and something as simple as enclosing a single column name with `[]` can change that behavior.

Comment: See the update above for this.

Comment: exactly that's why it's not correct to do a chained assignment. sometimes it works but that's dependent on various non trivial things

Comment: there is some caching going on so what you are doing is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assigning with two or more getitems/slices (chaining) may or may not work depending on the situation...

so you should **avoid** doing it!! You should rewrite to do each in one pass.*

There was quite a substantial amount of work in 0.11 (possibly before) to clear up this behaviour... Now pandas overloads these assignments to not care if it's a [view or a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), *if* you are doing this in one pass, which you should be doing, in general.
For example:

```
dfrm.loc[dfrm.A > 0.5, 'A'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

dfrm.loc[[dfrm.A > 0.5], ['B','C']] = 100 * np.random.rand(6, 2)
```

Also, generally good practise to specify that you are indexing by the label (with the loc):

```
dfrm.loc[dfrm.A > 0.5] = 100 * np.random.rand(6, 3)
```

You could also consider rewriting:

```
dfrm.loc[dfrm.A > 0.5] = 0.5 * dfrm.loc[dfrm.A > 0.5]
```

to

```
dfrm.loc[dfrm.A > 0.5] *= 0.5
```

*This is a surprising error in 0.8.1 (but seems to be fixed in later versions), perhaps a workaround (if the above doesn't work) is to set the fancy index first (`df_A_gt_half = dfrm.A > 0.5`) and then do the assignment using that... and are forced to use `ix` rather than `loc`.*

Comment: On the size comment: I picked 6 specifically because in my random data set, exactly 6 points were greater than 0.5 in the 'A' column. One could easily modify that for a different random set.

Comment: @EMS yeah, wasn't important, shouldn't have put that at the top :)

Comment: No worries. I updated the question after trying it in our sandbox Python that has Pandas 0.11. I still see all the same oddities about when `__setitem__` is invoked in the straightforward way.

Comment: @EMS yeah, all the odities come from doing the set items multiple times, do it only *once*.

Comment: ? I don't understand. Where am I doing `__setitem__` twice?

Comment: sorry, my bad, it's not necessarily set item that's multiple times, but any chaining of the `[]`s

Comment: I see, but actually chaining the `[]` has been the only way I can get it to perform single-column assignments in the expected way. The generalization to multiple columns is where it started acting weird. With single columns, I can't get `.ix` to do as well as chaining `[]`'s